# SKINNING - How to remove specific vertex relation to bone

Tags: rigging

I've create a model and a rig by myself to understand how it's working but i'm stuck with one thing : some vertex are related to a bone and I don't want it. Obviously to avoid that kind of result : (look at the pelvis which move withe the hand controller)

[image]

I tried to delete the relation but it's impossible to see the relation of a group of vertex, it's not listed anywhere because it's not an object but some vertex of this object.

Do you know how to solve that ?

Many thanks in advance,
François

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the vertex groups tab. Find the group with the same name as the hand has, select the skirt's vertexes in the 3d view and click on remove.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html